# Find Duplicate Files, but Specify a Directory to Keep

Tags: linux, bash, duplicate-files, fdupes

I am working on de-cluttering a company shared drive, and looking to remove duplicates.
Is there any duplicate finding program that allows you to specify which directory's duplicates are to be removed?

I would like to be able to do: `fdupes -rdN some_Folder master_folder` so that it preferentially keeps the duplicates in one folder over the other folder.

This involves thousands of files, so doing it by hand is not really an option. If rdfind's results file is the only way to do it, what's the best way to use that file?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all duplicates with `fdupes` and extend your command to delete everything it finds, except files in `master_folder`:

```
fdupes -r some_Folder master_folder | grep -v ^master_folder/ | xargs rm -v
```

Explanation:

- the output list of all duplicate files is sent to `grep`, which will output everything but lines beginning (`^`) with string `master_folder/`.
- this filtered list is sent one by one (using the `xargs` command) as an argument to `rm` command, so each of this files gets deleted. `-v` argument shows, which files actually got deleted

Caution: Be careful with the rm command, try first on some non-critical data!

Edit:
I added `-v` argument to `rm` command, because without it, the whole command is running absolutely silently, without output, which might be an unwanted behavior.